Why isn't there a button to add a virtual device in Android Studio?
After installing Android Studio, Flutter, Dart and the SDK, there is no way to select or add virtual devices.  This is running on Windows 11:

The only devices listed are remote and there are no buttons to add any other devices.  This does not seem to match up with any of the instructions for adding new virtual devices. The drop down menu "+" in the running devices window only shows the remote devices.  Does anyone have some idea of the issue here?
I've reinstalled Android Studio and SDKs multiple times, and tried File->Invalidate caches.

Right-click on the "Device Manager" heading and check "Show Toolbar":

And now there is the "+" button to add new devices:


Thank you!  I clicked on that bar dozens of times, but not once did I try clicking directly on the "Device Manager" text... so simple!  Thanks again.

Glad I could help. To signal to others that this helped you with your question you can accept this answer by ticking the checkbox next to it.
